# How can I parse MARC records with a Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, pcre, marc

I would like to parse a MARC record with a regular expression and return the field as the first captured group and the value as the second captured group. Here's what I've got thus far for the regex:

```
(\n[0-9]{3})[ 0-9]{4}([^\n]*)
```

The last capture group there `([^\n]*)` is capturing everything up until the next line break, which works great with lines like:

```
001    868229892 
100 1  Montgomery, L. M.|q(Lucy Maud),|d1874-1942.,|eauthor. 
245 10 Anne of Green Gables /|cL.M. Montgomery. 
250    Aladdin hardcover edition. 
264  1 New York :|bAladdin,|c2014. 
300    440 pages &#59;|c22 cm 
336    text|2rdacontent. 
337    unmediated|2rdamedia. 
338    volume|2rdacarrier.
```

However, when it comes to values which break over lines, the regex no longer works:

```
520    Anne, an eleven-year-old orphan, is sent by mistake to 
       live with a lonely, middle-aged brother and sister on a 
       Prince Edward Island farm and proceeds to make an 
       indelible impression on everyone around her. 
650  0 Shirley, Anne (Fictitious character)|vJuvenile fiction.
```

The next stop area should be the `650` above. So the regex should capture everything up until **a line break followed by 3 digits**.

I did try `([^\n0-9]*)` but that is interpreted as match anything other than digits or a line break *in any order*. I need it to match a line break and 3 digits *in that exact sequence*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this regex, as demonstrated on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eK8lN1/1):

`(\n[0-9]{3})[ 0-9]{4}([^\n]+(?:\n\s+[^\n]+)*)`

The capture group `([^\n]+(?:\n\s+[^\n]+)*)` matches

- any non-linebreaks: `[^\n]+`
- then any number of extra lines: `(?:\n\s+[^\n]+)*`

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative lookahead to the end to make sure the line break is followed by 3 digits. There are also a few things that could be done to shorten the regular expression.

```
(\n\d{3})[ \d]{4}((?:(?!\n\d{3}).)*)
```

Comment: Works well on regex101.